# Why summing up the forces doesn't work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, integration, centripetal-force

I was trying to find out what the force on a rotating semicircular disc would be, and I know I can take the angular velocity and multiply it by (the distance between center of mass and the axis of rotation), but I tried another way, I divided the semicircular disc into infinitely many semicircles and calculated the centripetal force on each then I added them all up (integrated) but it didn't give me the same answer and I just can't understand why?

[image]

(to make it more clear, why isn't the sum of the forces similar to the force acting on the disc)

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question since you have not shown your work. You made a mistake somewhere

Comment: Yes, it does work. However, be aware that "check my work" questions are explicitly off topic here

Comment: Unfortunately, that will make it a "check my work" question which is off topic. You made a mistake, but this site won't help you find it. Maybe try physicsforums.com instead. There you have to show your work, but check my work questions are on topic

Comment: Keep in mind, that the center of mass of a semicircle does not lie on the semicircle.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian mechanics forces are applied to a point. What you consider the point depends on the context of your problem. In particular, here you may have (at least) two different situations:

- Considering motion of the disk as a whole, i.e., the motion of its center-of-mass. In this case you sum all the forces applied to the disk.
- Considering motion of parts of the disk, including its rotation - in this case the forces applied to different parts of the disk cannot be added, since they are not applied to the same point/object.

Comment: But won't the overall force be distributed among each of them (something similar to what we do in objects with rope between them), and if not then where is that force coming from?

Comment: Physically it is distributed among them. The point is what are you really trying to look at? If the net force on the disk is zero, its center of mass is not moving, but it can be rotating, because the forces are applied to different parts of it (e.g., at the axis and at the edge).  In addition, if it is elastic, the forces may cause the disk change its shape.

Comment: OK forgive my ignorance, but I still can't get why I can't treat it as a bunch of balls connected to a rope with the mass of each ball representing the mass of the part I'm taking of the disc and the distance between it and the axis of rotation being the distance between that part and the axis?

Comment: What I am saying is that in some cases you can treat it as a whole, and in other cases it doesn't. It is not clear from yoru question what exactly is the problem - try reformulating it or adding more details.

Comment: My bad I updated, I hope it's better now

Comment: You should be able to sum the reaction forces at the axle.